# How to create a scrolling view window that only shows data that meets a certain criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to create a scrollable view window that only displays rows of data that meet specific criteria. I have created the scrollable view window with a Form Control Scroll Bar and set it up in cell `B28`. I then used an offset formula to grab data from a different sheet in the workbook.

```
=OFFSET('DATA DUMP'!B3,$B$28,0)
```

I did this for columns `G`, `F`, and `I` as well. I am wondering if it is possible to only show rows that contain the value "No" in column `G`. I tried to filter the column headers but I found that this did not work with the scrollbar. Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the scrollable view window you created? Or detail how you did this? I'm having trouble picturing this.

Comment: [Screenshot](http://prntscr.com/u343lv)

I only want values in "Complete" to show "No"

Comment: Still not clear how you made that. Consider using a pivot table. You can use slicers to filter pivot tables.

Comment: Hi @Preston,,, I've seen the screen shot,, you need to apply formula filter records, possibly an array (CSE) formula,,, in area (Range) controlled by Scroll bar, help U to view particular records or if possible share either the WB on cloud or the sample data you need to filter by criteria !

Answer (score 0):

I cannot address the scroll bar as I've no experience with either one available in the Developer tab (Form Control or Active X Control). However, when it comes to populating whatever region it controls I can say a couple things:

1. I cannot see how that `OFFSET()` formula does anything needing scrolling unless you will never want to see more than one row at a time and the scrolling is left-right. Since that seems unlikely, I will address getting (usually, one would think) more than one row:  in fact, getting all the rows that have "No" in the "Complete" column. Then, since "unlikely" is not the same as "never" I will also address a single row being obtained.
2. As `Rajesh S` says, the `FILTER()` function is your friend here. However, if you have `Spill` functionality, as most seem to finally, if using O365, you will NOT need to use CSE (the old style for getting an array). However, it does present a problem given you do not want contiguous columns from your data source.

`FILTER()` will take non-contiguous column ranges in whatever way one can present them in Excel. `INDEX()` is a good way to do that. HOWEVER, it will then simply give you all the columns from the leftmost to the rightmost, regardless of your careful effort to specify only four in your example. So you will get eight columns, four with 0's. To get these four non-contiguous columns, you are best served by a "helper table."

Most have heard of "helper columns" and my favorite, a "helper page", but many people hate them. Not only do they consider them inelegant, but there's the whole problem of where to put them, physically, and if they have to exist in the final version, how to not have them being ugly and inelegant in their finished product, not to mention not having them carelessly (or worse? on purpose...) edited by users.

But you need it here. You need to build the four columns of your desired output table somewhere, perhaps a nice, hidden worksheet that takes real effort to get to. But somewhere.

Build four columns, your columns B, G, F, and I columns by first crafting the desired output from column A. I am giving the range of cells you want as B3:B102, but obviously, you can edit the row values to whatever is needed. Even be clever about it and build them dynamically. For column B, use:

```
=FILTER(B3:B102,$I$3:$I$102="No")
```

This tells it to collect records from column B, to look at the value of the corresponding rows in column I and take only those records in column B that see a "No" in their column I cell.

Enter that in cell B3. Then copy and paste it to cells F3, G3, and I3. It will change the first range to match those columns. This is the easy way to make sure the exact right formula is built for each. Then the fun trick which not only gets rid of the empty columns, but keeps the formula in each column exactly as it is now:  select cell G3 and drag it over to cell C3 and drop it. Then do the same for F3 except drop it on cell D3 and likewise for cell I3, dropping it on cell E3.

Now you have perfect formulas in the data source's column order of B, G, F, then I. In the helper table's columns B, C, D, and E. Leave them like that, or gab all four and drag to A3:D3 if you prefer. Helper table is now all set.

Go to the output page and create one more `FILTER()` formula in, I believe, cell B28. This time, it will refer to the helper table/range, not the source data. Since there are no extra columns (i.e.:  the helper table's columns are contiguous, not separated), you need a single formula in cell B28:

```
=FILTER(A3#:D3#,A3#=A3#)
```

This time it tells Excel to use the `Spill` ranges A3#, B3#, C3#, and D3 (A3#:D3#). You can highlight them, by the way, and press `F4` to make them absolute to protect them from row insertions and such. Just this one formula specifying those `Spill` ranges like that will collect all four columns from the helper table. For criteria, I use the first column's cells equalling themselves so all the cells in the helper table are collected into your output. Couple other way to be all-inclusive like that and I'm sure someone will run time tests someday and go on about it like they used to with `VLOOKUP()` vs. `INDEX/MATCH` but for now, it's all good, so long as you really get them all with whatever technique you use.

A very clean little way to fill your ouitput using a single formula in said output, even though there is a helper table in the middle, somewhere out of the way.

If you want a single record, specified as you do in the `OFFSET()` formula you gave, just use that criteria WITH the "No" criteria. But I honestly don't see all those pieces you give matching up. Just saying the function like that does hint at wanting a single record, though if B28 is the output cell, that would be circular so..., but then talking about wanting only records that say "No" in the "Complete" column hints at wanting multiple records at a time. But it could still mean the former, just that you want nothing at all shown if the record number you provide to the `OFFSET()` function is complete. So you make the call. It's just a matter of limiting it further. Use `AND()` in the criteria like so, perhaps:

```
=FILTER(B3:B102,  AND($I$3:$I$102="No",  OFFSET('DATA DUMP'!B3,$B$28,0))  )
```

So both conditions have to be `TRUE` to show a record.

Which brings up one last thing about `FILTER()`:  it will take a third parameter (just add at the end) that gives a message you wish to give if no matching record/s is/are found. Just a string so something like `"No record matches."`

The use of `FILTER()` like this can give one tremendous granularity in presenting data to users that is completely appropriate to their tasks and security and "exposure to just what data they should be allowed to see" situations. To make that really sing though, you need data entry controls so they can only save additions, changes, and deletions back to the source data if it passes certain tests you might devise. Since you pick the columns they see, as well as filtering the rows, a frontline user might not see the addresses of customers and so might not stalk female voices that sound nice. And so on, whatever your needs, fine, fine granularity is completely available. The function is also usable with more than one table so long as you have a reliable way to link the disparate data sets. You always have full control over the source since your own data entry forms handle actual changes to it. The users never even see the choices made in the helper table/s and so might have a hard time guessing what even is available in addition to what they see, and furthermore, since they never see the names even of the actual data columns or table/range names themselves, writing formulas in their workspace that reference one column after another, prospecting as it were, is not possible. Limits them greatly in trying to do things they are not suppposed to. If output to printers and files is limited to being done in your data controls, you control that as well.

But you just need the simple version above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=INDEX('Data Dump'!B$3:B$95,SMALL(IF('Data Dump'!$B$3:$B$95="no",SEQUENCE(ROWS('Data Dump'!B$3:B$95))),$B$28 + ROW()-1))

=INDEX('Data Dump'!E$3:E$95,SMALL(IF('Data Dump'!$B$3:$B$95="no",SEQUENCE(ROWS('Data Dump'!E$3:E$95))),$B$28 + ROW()-1))
```

This works for B3:B95 and only returns those containing "no", just change this to suit it references B28 as the index for the scroll bar. To shift columns use the second formula as a guide.

the row() - 1 is where you adapt for the location of the formula, in the formula above it is on row 2 and down so it is -1, if you were starting on row 3 you would change to -2 etc.

The scroll works well but returns an error when you run out of "no" results, use iferror to correct for this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Data Dump'!B$3:B$95,SMALL(IF('Data Dump'!$B$3:$B$95="no",SEQUENCE(ROWS('Data Dump'!B$3:B$95))),$B$28 + ROW()-1)),"")
```

[image]